# Can't get my WebWorker to work after migration from Webpack to Vite

Tags: webpack, vite, web-worker

For a number of reasons I am migrating an application using a WebWorker from React to SoliJS. With React I was relying on the CRA which is using Webpack and with SolidJS I am now relying on a template which is using Vite.

With Webpack I had been able to access the WebWorker using this simple method:

```
new Worker(new URL('./dispatcher-worker', import.meta.url));
```

My WebWorker imports stuff from other modules and without modification that gives "SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module" errors in both Firefox and Chrome when served by Vite (in dev mode).

A few searches made me understand that this was because by default I was using "classic" WebWorkers where I should be using "module" WebWorkers and that Webpack was just hiding this complexity by some kind of magic and I updates this by:

```
new Worker(new URL('./dispatcher-worker', import.meta.url), {
    type: 'module',
})
```

After a few more issues related to missing polyfills I got it working for Chrome (and Webview) but I still get the same error in Firefox which does no support WebWorker modules.

Is there way to reproduce with Vite the transformations that make WebWorker modules work in Firefox ?

Comment: I was getting the same error with web workers and imports with Vite.Try running.. ."npm run build" then run "npm run preview" and see if it works.

Comment: For SolidJS the command to run vite preview is "npm run serve" but you're right, it does work. The problem seems to be specific to the dev mode (npm run start), then, thanks for the tip !